# How does the CXC Language Cloud BeGlobal API Key work?

Tags: translation-manager, language-cloud

I set up SDL Tridion 2013 SP1's Translation Manager with SDL Language Cloud as described in this [write-up](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/03/03/setting-up-sdl-language-cloud-on-sdl-tridion-2013-sp1).

**How does Translation Manager and the BeGlobal API Key work?**

I want to see if we could maybe run training on AWS EC2 instances, each with the same BeGlobal API Key.

Would there be a conflict between separate Translation Manager setups* sending and/or retrieving translations with the same key?

*Each EC2 instance would be a "clone" of an AWS AMI with the same database, configuration, TCM-ids, etc.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a demo AMI used worldwide by multiple folks to create their own AWS instances based on it, and we all share the same demo Language Cloud / BeGlobal API key without conflict. We use it to showcase the nice integration of Tridion with SDL Language Cloud.

Comment: +1 for confirming. Does this only work for 2013 SP1?

Comment: Yes BeGlobal support was introduced with SP1. The documentation confirms: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/undefined/undefined/GUID-D71ECE3E-75AE-43A2-A6EE-BE95B91FC48B